# Fabric Android Unity cannot initialize

Tags: android, google-fabric

I am trying to add and initialize Crashlytics inside of Unity and am constantly met with:

```
AndroidJavaException: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
07-20 16:29:35.457 30466 30512 I Unity   : install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
07-20 16:29:35.457 30466 30512 I Unity   : io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
07-20 16:29:35.457 30466 30512 I Unity   : install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
07-20 16:29:35.457 30466 30512 I Unity   :     at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:234)
07-20 16:29:35.457 30466 30512 I Unity   :     at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:207)
07-20 16:29:35.457 30466 30512 I Unity   :     at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
07-20 16:29:35.457 30466 30512 I Unity   :     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
07-20 16:29:35.457 30466 30512 I Unity   :     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
```

I would like to stick with Manual initialization for use case, have definitely already "Prepare"d Fabric and have a Fabric/Crashytics account. The documentation doesn't really help that I've seen.

Has anyone had success with this on Android using C# building?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So found out the problem had to do with missing the resources in the APK. The error is a bit unhelpful, it's actually complaining that the "buildId" was not able to be found. So if you have the issue, ensure that you check your resources in your final APK.